# How to add MatButtonModule Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { JoinUsComponent } from './join-us/join-us.component';
import { CareersComponent } from './careers/careers.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavComponent,
    JoinUsComponent,
    CareersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule, // Doesn't know what this is
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Basically I am trying to use the MatButtonModule in my app.module.ts file but it doesn't seem to be able to find the name and has no idea on what it is. Am I doing something wrong, missing something, I've looked everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module must be imported to be able to use them.

In your case you need to import `MatButtonModule` with the following:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

You may refer to the angular API [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api) for this button